# blur/focusout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

I have multiple divs with the same class-'.new-contact.clearfix.invite'. The divs contain some inputs.

I want to perform validation on the form (which its class is 'invitePartners) only when I click/enter some input in different line (each div is a different line).

I tried the following, but the event is not triggered:

```
  $('.invite').on('blur','.new-contact.clearfix.invite', function () {
 $('.invitePartners').valid()
})
```

Example of the div's HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="new-contact clearfix invite">
            <div class="first-name invite">
                <input type="text" id="firstName1" class="signup-input firstName required" name="first[1]" placeholder="">
            </div>
        <div class="last-name">
                <input type="text" id="lastName1" class="signup-input lastName" name="last[1]" placeholder="optional">
            </div>
                <input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input mail" name="email[1]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com" aria-invalid="true">
                <span class="common-sprite sign-up-cross first clone"></span>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post HTML code.

Comment: The `.valid()` method is not part of the jQuery library and none of your elements contain the `.invitePartners` class.  Please fix your OP so that it makes more sense.

Comment: If you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, then I suggest that you thoroughly review the documentation as there is **no need** to write your own `blur` event handlers to achieve validation.  This is all done automatically by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from JQuery `on` help page :

> The **focus** and **blur** events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser **focusin** and **focusout** events that do bubble.

This mean that your blur event don't go up the DOM when fired from `.new-contact.clearfix.invite` and so cannot be catch up by `.invite`

Comment: I understand it. But what can I do instead?

Comment: you can use **focusin** and **focusout** instread of **blur**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('blur','.new-contact.clearfix.invite input', function () {
   $('.invitePartners').valid()
});
```

Comment: Rajiv007- I don't want the input

Comment: you can only have blur event firing on "inputs" not on "divs".

Comment: @Rajiv007- I understood it. So what can i do for trigger a function when I move to another div/row?

Comment: tell me how will you know that you are moving to another div/row...clicking or using "tab". @SaritSara

Comment: Rajiv007- by clicking

Comment: the how about using the "click" event instead of "blur/focusout etc". But you need to have unique ids for each divs to distinguish.

Comment: you can add unique ids and the it will be like:  $(this).click(function(){ $('.invitePartners').valid() });

Comment: @Rajiv007- I can't the id's are given dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try .focusout() ...

```
$('.new-contact.clearfix.invite').focusout(function () {
    $('.invitePartners').valid();
});
```

It's not really clear what your elements are, you should post your HTML in your question.    If you are just trying to use elements that are related to the element blurred, you may need to use something like ...

```
$('.invitePartners', this).valid();
```

Comment: the valid() occurs even when I move between the inputs in the same div- not good

Comment: OK, then I Don't understand what you are asking.  The blur or focusout will occur whenever the element loses focus.  What behavior are you wanting then?

Comment: Please post your HTML